# In task.json "Required" can have a expression or not?

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task

In `Task.json`, for each input field the required field can be kept. This verify the field is mandatory or not.

I want to make a field `required = true` if the above field has a value "ABCD" and `required = false` if the above field value is something else. How can I achieve this ? In both case I have to show the field.

Can I add Expression to evaluate

```
 {
    "name": "path",
    "type": "string",
    "label": "Path",
    "required": "false",
    "validation": {          
      "expression":"isMatch(value,'^$|\\.(?i:)(?:png|jpeg)$','IgnoreCase')",
      "message": "Choose a valid file."
    },
    "helpMarkDown": "Provide a path"
  },
```

Comment: Hi Joy, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding expression to required field is not yet achieved. Is this allowed? How it can be.

My alternate solution was to have two different input entries with same label and mutually opposite visibleRule. So in the code I should have same visibleRule condition to be checked before accessing the user input.
Example:

```
"inputs": [
    {
        "name": "targetPath1",
        "type": "radio",
        "label": "targetPath",
        "defaultValue": "filePath",
        "helpMarkDown": "Target script type: File Path or path",
        "options": {
            "filePath": "File Path",
            "path": "Path"
         }
    },
    {
        "name": "filePath1",
        "type": "filePath",
        "label": "Script Path",
        "visibleRule": "targetType = filePath",
        "required": true,
        "helpMarkDown": "If the user selects the "File Path" above then Script Path will be a mandatory field"
    },
    {
        "name": "filePath2",
        "type": "filePath",
        "label": "Script Path",
        "visibleRule": "targetType = path",
        "required": false,
        "helpMarkDown": "If the user selects the "File Path" above then Script Path will be a optional field"         
    }
]
```

While accessing these fields inside the code.

```
var path;
var targetPath = tl.getInput("targetPath1");
If(targetPath == "filePath")
path = tl.getInput("filePath1");
If(targetPath == "path")
path = tl.getInput("filePath2");
```

Comment: That's nice for a classic pipeline.. what about a yaml pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

We need define the value of field 1 in the task.json file, then select the field 1 value to configure the field value, we can refer to [power shell task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/PowerShellV2/task.json) to do this.

Task.json Sample:

```
 "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "targetPath1",
            "type": "radio",
            "label": "targetPath",
            "required": false,
            "defaultValue": "filePath",
            "helpMarkDown": "Target script type: File Path or path",
            "options": {
                "filePath": "File Path",
                "path": "Path"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "filePath",
            "type": "filePath",
            "label": "Script Path",
            "visibleRule": "targetType = filePath",
            "required": true,
            "defaultValue": "",
            "helpMarkDown": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "path",
            "type": "filePath",
            "label": "Path",
            "visibleRule": "targetType = filePath",
            "required": true,
            "defaultValue": "",
            "helpMarkDown": ""
        }
        {
            "name": "path1",
            "type": "filePath",
            "label": "Path1",
            "visibleRule": "targetType = filePath",
            "required": false,
            "defaultValue": "",
            "helpMarkDown": ""
        }
]
```

Then we can use it in the [task.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/PowerShellV2/powershell.ts) file and set the expression.

In addition, if you do not want to change the field 2 name, we can define the same field 2 in the different json files and use it in the task.ts field.