# Azure custom task input - conditional required

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

I got an Azure custom task with inputs defined in its task.json file. Can I make an input required based on the value of another input?

Pseudo code of what I mean (the required of the 2nd input is the main thing here):

```
{
  "name": "boolInput",
  "type": "boolean",
  "required": true,
  "label": "Do we require the string input",
  "defaultValue": "true",
},
{
  "name": "stringInput",
  "type": "string",
  "required": "boolInput = true",
  "label": "My string input",
  "defaultValue": "initialVal",
},
```

The solution should work with a yaml pipeline, not a classic one.

Comment: Related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64136616/in-task-json-required-can-have-a-expression-or-not
This solution uses an alternate paths option.

Comment: @JamesSheils That's close but using visibleRule works for classic pipelines only. In my case I'm using a yaml pipeline so it won't work. Edited the question with that info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option. you can see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/tasks.schema.json) the `task.json` schema:

```
"required": {
  "type": "boolean",
  "description": "Whether the input is a required field (default is false).",
  "default": false
},
```

Comment: Do you might know of a work around to do something like I need? Like it was done for a classic pipeline with the visible rule?

Comment: No :/ I guess you need to handle it in your code and make good documentation...